# Getting a KeyError in Python while making War

Tags: python

My assignment is to make the card game War. I am trying to use  `random.shuffle()` to shuffle my deck of cards and then use `deck.popitem()` to get a random set of key value pairs, but no matter where I put the `random.shuffle()` I always get a KeyError.

Here is my code:

```
import random

NUMBER = 1

def main():

    deck = create_deck()

    player_name = input("Player Name: ")
    print('\nWelcome to the Game of War ', player_name, '!', sep = '')
    print("Press 'Enter' to Start a Game:")

    user_input = input("\n")

    if user_input.upper() == '':
        deal_cards(deck, NUMBER, player_name)



# define create deck===================
def create_deck():

    deck = {'Ace of Spades': 1, '2 of Spades': 2, '3 of Spades': 3, '4 of Spades': 4, 
        '5 of Spades': 5, '6 of Spades': 6, '7 of Spades': 7, '8 of Spades': 8,
        '9 of Spades': 9, '10 of Spades': 10, 'Jack of Spades': 11, 
        'Queen of Spades': 12, 'King of Spades': 13,

        'Ace of Clubs': 1, '2 of Clubs': 2, '3 of Clubs': 3, '4 of Clubs': 4, 
        '5 of Clubs': 5, '6 of Clubs': 6, '7 of Clubs': 7, '8 of Clubs': 8,
        '9 of Clubs': 9, '10 of Clubs': 10, 'Jack of Clubs': 11, 
        'Queen of Clubs': 12, 'King of Clubs': 13,

        'Ace of Diamonds': 1, '2 of Diamonds': 2, '3 of Diamonds': 3, '4 of Diamonds': 4, 
        '5 of Diamonds': 5, '6 of Diamonds': 6, '7 of Diamonds': 7, '8 of Diamonds': 8,
        '9 of Diamonds': 9, '10 of Diamonds': 10, 'Jack of Diamonds': 11, 
        'Queen of Diamonds': 12, 'King of Diamonds': 13,

        'Ace of Hearts': 1, '2 of Hearts': 2, '3 of Hearts': 3, '4 of Hearts': 4, 
        '5 of Hearts': 5, '6 of Hearts': 6, '7 of Hearts': 7, '8 of Hearts': 8,
        '9 of Hearts': 9, '10 of Hearts': 10, 'Jack of Hearts': 11, 
        'Queen of Hearts': 12, 'King of Hearts': 13,


        }

    random.shuffle(deck)

    return deck

# define deal cards==============
    def deal_cards(deck, num, p_name):

    # Starting hand value
    p_value = 0
    c_value = 0

    # Is number of cards greater than the number of cards in deck
    if num > len(deck):
    num = len(deck)

    # Deal Cards and check value
    while num < len(deck):
    for count in range(num):
      card, value = deck.popitem()
      p_value = value
      print(p_name, "'s card: ", card, sep = '')
      card, value = deck.popitem()
      c_value = value
      print("Computer's Card:", card)

      if p_value > c_value:
        print('\n', p_name, ' has won the hand!', sep = '')
      elif c_value > p_value:
        print('\nThe Computer has won the hand!')


      input()

main()
```

Comment: I don't think you can shuffle a `dict`, as they are unordered anyway.  You can get a list of the keys and then shuffle that: `cards = list(deck.keys()) random.shuffle(cards) return cards`.

Comment: I tried that and I cannot use the popitem() method to pick a random pair in a list.

Comment: What do you mean by that?  What issue is `popitem()` giving you?  Have you tried moving `deck` outside of the function so that you can look up values based on keys?  You can also try using `list(deck.items())` instead.

Answer (score 1):

As you can't shuffle a dict (to my knowledge), I propose you this solution: Transform desk to a list (than can be shuffled).

```
import random

deck = [{'Ace of Spades': 1}, {'2 of Spades': 2}, {'3 of Spades': 3}, {'4 of Spades': 4}, 
    {'5 of Spades': 5}, {'6 of Spades': 6}, {'7 of Spades': 7}, {'8 of Spades': 8},
    {'9 of Spades': 9}, {'10 of Spades': 10}, {'Jack of Spades': 11}, 
    {'Queen of Spades': 12}, {'King of Spades': 13},
    {'Ace of Clubs': 1}, {'2 of Clubs': 2}, {'3 of Clubs': 3}, {'4 of Clubs': 4}, 
    {'5 of Clubs': 5}, {'6 of Clubs': 6}, {'7 of Clubs': 7}, {'8 of Clubs': 8},
    {'9 of Clubs': 9}, {'10 of Clubs': 10}, {'Jack of Clubs': 11}, 
    {'Queen of Clubs': 12}, {'King of Clubs': 13},
    {'Ace of Diamonds': 1}, {'2 of Diamonds': 2}, {'3 of Diamonds': 3}, {'4 of Diamonds': 4}, 
    {'5 of Diamonds': 5}, {'6 of Diamonds': 6}, {'7 of Diamonds': 7}, {'8 of Diamonds': 8},
    {'9 of Diamonds': 9}, {'10 of Diamonds': 10}, {'Jack of Diamonds': 11}, 
    {'Queen of Diamonds': 12}, {'King of Diamonds': 13},
    {'Ace of Hearts': 1}, {'2 of Hearts': 2}, {'3 of Hearts': 3}, {'4 of Hearts': 4}, 
    {'5 of Hearts': 5}, {'6 of Hearts': 6}, {'7 of Hearts': 7}, {'8 of Hearts': 8},
    {'9 of Hearts': 9}, {'10 of Hearts': 10}, {'Jack of Hearts': 11}, 
    {'Queen of Hearts': 12}, {'King of Hearts': 13}
    ]

random.shuffle(deck)
```

**Edit** To be able to use `popitem()`:

```
import random

deck = [('Ace of Spades', 1), ('2 of Spades', 2), ('3 of Spades', 3), ('4 of Spades', 4), 
    ('5 of Spades', 5), ('6 of Spades', 6), ('7 of Spades', 7), ('8 of Spades', 8), 
    ('9 of Spades', 9), ('10 of Spades', 10), ('Jack of Spades', 11), 
    ('Queen of Spades', 12), ('King of Spades', 13), 
    ('Ace of Clubs', 1), ('2 of Clubs', 2), ('3 of Clubs', 3), ('4 of Clubs', 4), 
    ('5 of Clubs', 5), ('6 of Clubs', 6), ('7 of Clubs', 7), ('8 of Clubs', 8), 
    ('9 of Clubs', 9), ('10 of Clubs', 10), ('Jack of Clubs', 11), 
    ('Queen of Clubs', 12), ('King of Clubs', 13), 
    ('Ace of Diamonds', 1), ('2 of Diamonds', 2), ('3 of Diamonds', 3), ('4 of Diamonds', 4), 
    ('5 of Diamonds', 5), ('6 of Diamonds', 6), ('7 of Diamonds', 7), ('8 of Diamonds', 8), 
    ('9 of Diamonds', 9), ('10 of Diamonds', 10), ('Jack of Diamonds', 11), 
    ('Queen of Diamonds', 12), ('King of Diamonds', 13), 
    ('Ace of Hearts', 1), ('2 of Hearts', 2), ('3 of Hearts', 3), ('4 of Hearts', 4), 
    ('5 of Hearts', 5), ('6 of Hearts', 6), ('7 of Hearts', 7), ('8 of Hearts', 8), 
    ('9 of Hearts', 9), ('10 of Hearts', 10), ('Jack of Hearts', 11), 
    ('Queen of Hearts', 12), ('King of Hearts', 13)
    ]

random.shuffle(deck)
deck = dict(deck)
print deck.popitem()
```

Comment: If I do that I cannot use the popitem() method to get a random pair

Comment: If i may ask, do you really need to shuffle if you use the `popitem` function after?

Comment: Try using an list of tuples instead of dicts.

Comment: @Nuageux the reason I am shuffling is because if I dont shuffle and only use the popitem() function than every time I run the game it will give me the same cards in the same order every time. To see what I mean you can remove the shuffle function and run the code. You will get the same pair of cards every time you restart the program.

Comment: @Opawl I change the format again, so you can have a version that can use popitem() as you needed. Unfortunately, it always returns 8 or 10 of Hearts on my computer. I might have a broken seed, not sure though. Can you try on your computer to check?

Comment: @Nuageux I was able to collaborate with a friend to get the code working. we kept the `deck` as a dictionary and use the following code to access the key value pair. `card, p_val = random.choice(list(deck.items()))` and then added a line of code to take that pair out of the dictionary. Thank you for the help!

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad you find a way that suits you. I thought about getting a random item without shuffling but it seems so important to you that i then forget to propose it... Feel free to use ideas from my other proposition though!

Answer (score 0):

I change a few things in your original code, to fix a few issues.

Since it is redundant to set a value for each card and since the initialization of your deck is really long, I modify the declaration of *deck*:
there are no more value, instead i created a function that evaluate the card. So, if you implement a new game, you just have to change this function. I kept the previous format, but I included the itertools function in order to have the minimal declaration length (On one side, the *level* of the card, on the other side the color).

In the *deal_cards* function, I just adapt the code in order to fit the previous changes.

I also change your prints. You should have a look at %s, %d, %f... if you don't know them, it is very useful to include variables in string.

Hope this helps,

```
import random
import itertools

NUMBER = 1

def main():

    deck = create_deck()

    player_name = raw_input("Player Name: ")
    print('\nWelcome to the Game of War %s!' % player_name)
    print("Press 'Enter' to Start a Game:")

    user_input = raw_input("\n")

    if user_input.upper() == '':
        deal_cards(deck, NUMBER, player_name)

# define create deck===================
def create_deck():
    deck = list(itertools.product(
            itertools.chain(xrange(2, 11), ('Jack', 'Queen', 'King', 'Ace')),
            (' of Hearts', ' of Diamonds', ' of Clubs', ' of Spades'),
            ))

    random.shuffle(deck)
    deck = dict(deck)
    return deck

def evaluate(card):
    if card[0] == 'Jack':
        return 11
    elif card[0] == 'Queen':
        return 12
    elif card[0] == 'King':
        return 13
    elif card[0] == 'Ace':
        return 1
    return card[0]

# define deal cards==============
def deal_cards(deck, num, p_name):

    # Starting hand value
    p_value = 0
    c_value = 0

    # Is number of cards greater than the number of cards in deck
    if num > len(deck):
        num = len(deck)

    # Deal Cards and check value
    while num < len(deck):
        for count in range(num):
            card = deck.popitem()
            p_value = evaluate(card)
            print("%s's card: %s%s" % (p_name, card[0], card[1]))
            card = deck.popitem()
            p_value = evaluate(card)
            print("Computer's Card: %s%s" % (card[0], card[1]))

            if p_value > c_value:
                print('\n%s has won the hand!' % p_name)
            elif c_value > p_value:
                print('\nThe Computer has won the hand!')

        raw_input()

main()
```